# HOw to remove the comments section from WP Job Manager Resumes?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I'm using WP Job Manager plugin with the resumes extension.
The problem I am having is that on the bottom of the resumes pages there is a "comments" section which I do not want there. Please see: https://prnt.sc/10g7c2m

Under the WordPress settings>discussion menu, the checkbox for "Allow people to submit comments on new posts" is unchecked. Pls see: https://prnt.sc/10g78rf

I am also using the super socializer plugin and I have unchecked the "enable social commenting" checkbox, pls see: https://prnt.sc/10g7ctp

I have also deleted code in functions.php file which may have been causing this but the comments section is still there.

Does anybody know what may be causing this and how I can get rid of it pls?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your themes functions.php and it should disable them. if it still appears the theme you are using may not check to see if comments are enabled for custom post type

```
   add_action( 'init', 'post_type_resume_disable_comments', 999 );
    
    function remove_custom_post_type_comments() {
        remove_post_type_support( 'resume', 'comments' );
    }
```